# How to prevent Visual Studio 2019 [16.10.3] from auto page refresh in browser when changing any .js file?

Tags: visual-studio, hot-reload

After upgrading to Visual Studio Community 2019 [16.10.3] from [16.9.x] Chrome gets updated every time I save any javascript file. In my workflow it is annoying and does not bring my work any benefits. How to disable this feature?
I spent couple hours on searching the internet for the answer, but failed. It may be related to Hot Reload feature, but I still did not find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also want to disable this and what I found is that a javascript file named *aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js* is injected into the rendered page. The code in that file sets up a web socket to your web server which then allows the web server to issue a remote refresh of the browser. The browser refresh is triggered by something called **dotnet watch**, which is a process watching all the files in your project to see if any have changed.

You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-5.0#run-net-core-cli-commands-using-dotnet-watch

Apparently this is a new feature in VS2019 for ASP .NET Core apps and is enabled by default.

**HOW TO DISABLE**

1. Go to Tools > ⚙ Options > Projects and Solutions > ASP .NET Core
2. Select Auto build and refresh browser after saving changes in Auto build and refresh option

Comment: Did this, among other things, restarted visual studio and doesn't work. Really fed up with 2022, all the new AI tracking, removal of 1000 things, adding 1000 more options on by default....  really messing up my workflow. Microsoft proves once again how absolutely braindead they are when it comes to their customers... and developers that rely on their crap software.